# Python list looping to output averages - too many records returned

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list MyList1 below

```
[('128-F,2825', '3'), ('128-F,2854', '4'), ('128-F,2913', '5'), ('128-F,3210', '5'), ('128-F,3301', '4'), ('128-F,4771', '4'), ('128-M,1268', '4'), ('128-M,235', '5'), ('128-M,3367', '5'), ('128-M,4647', '5'), ('128-M,4795', '5'), ('128-M,5627', '3'), ('96-F,2041', '4'), ('96-F,3755', '4'), ('96-F,4946', '5'), ('96-F,5458', '3'), ('96-F,5643', '4'), ('96-F,5812', '2'), ('96-M,1671', '5'), ('96-M,386', '4'), ('96-M,3985', '4'), ('96-M,4169', '5'), ('96-M,5468', '4'), ('96-M,5848', '4'), ('96-M,889', '3')]
```

Which is generated from a dictionary and sorted,

```
MyList1 = [(k,v) for k,v in MyDict.items()]
MyList1.sort()
```

I wrote the newbie code to loop and calculate the average,

```
rec = " "
for i in range(len(MyList1)):
    #try:
        x = (MyList1[i][0].split(',')[0])
        y = int(MyList1[i][1])
        if rec != x:
            rec = x
            CurrCount = 1
            ThisRating = y
            CurrAvg = y / CurrCount
            #print('1', x, CurrAvg)
        elif rec == x:
            ThisRating = ThisRating + y
            CurrCount += 1
            CurrAvg = ThisRating / CurrCount
        else:
            print(x, 'no rating')

        print(x, CurrAvg)
    #except:
        #pass
```

The result I wanted is,

```
128 F   4.166666667
128 M   4.5
96  F   3.666666667
96  M   4.142857143
```

But I got the following instead.  The formula is working but Python is returning every iteration and not only the last record per combo.

```
128-F 3.0
128-F 3.5
128-F 4.0
128-F 4.25
128-F 4.2
128-F 4.166666666666667
128-M 4.0
128-M 4.5
128-M 4.666666666666667
128-M 4.75
128-M 4.8
128-M 4.5
96-F 4.0
96-F 4.0
96-F 4.333333333333333
96-F 4.0
96-F 4.0
96-F 3.6666666666666665
96-M 5.0
96-M 4.5
96-M 4.333333333333333
96-M 4.5
96-M 4.4
96-M 4.333333333333333
96-M 4.142857142857143
```

Can anyone please help me with what I did wrong with my code and how to correct it, please?

***Edit***
Sample dictionary included as requested,

```
dict_items([('128-F,2854', '4'), ('96-M,3985', '4'), ('128-F,3210', '5'), ('96-F,3755', '4'), ('128-F,2913', '5'), ('128-M,4647', '5'), ('128-F,4771', '4'), ('96-F,4946', '5'), ('128-M,4795', '5'), ('128-M,1268', '4'), ('96-M,5468', '4'), ('96-M,889', '3'), ('96-F,2041', '4'), ('128-M,5627', '3'), ('96-F,5643', '4'), ('128-M,235', '5'), ('96-M,5848', '4'), ('96-M,386', '4'), ('96-M,4169', '5'), ('96-F,5812', '2'), ('128-F,3301', '4'), ('128-M,3367', '5'), ('96-F,5458', '3'), ('96-M,1671', '5'), ('128-F,2825', '3')])
```

Thanks, Lobbie

Comment: Can you show sample of the actual dictionary from which you are creating list?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar - have included the dictionary sample in the question as requested.  Thanks.

Comment: Matthias's solution is the one you are looking for, beat me to it!! :D

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar, Thank you for responding too.  Both Matthias Schreiber and Byte Commander answers below worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you can use enumerate to make your life easier:

```
for i, pair in enumerate(MyList1):
```

(although the i and enumerate are kind of unnecessary for this example, it's still a good thing to keep in mind).
and then also the next lines like this:

```
x = pair[0].split(',')[0]
y = int(pair[1])
```

So this is a quick example I made which does exactly what you want:

```
l = [('128-F,2825', '3'), ('128-F,2854', '4'), ('128-F,2913', '5'), ('128-F,3210', '5'), ('128-F,3301', '4'), ('128-F,4771', '4'), ('128-M,1268', '4'), ('128-M,235', '5'), ('128-M,3367', '5'), ('128-M,4647', '5'), ('128-M,4795', '5'), ('128-M,5627', '3'), ('96-F,2041', '4'), ('96-F,3755', '4'), ('96-F,4946', '5'), ('96-F,5458', '3'), ('96-F,5643', '4'), ('96-F,5812', '2'), ('96-M,1671', '5'), ('96-M,386', '4'), ('96-M,3985', '4'), ('96-M,4169', '5'), ('96-M,5468', '4'), ('96-M,5848', '4'), ('96-M,889', '3')]

result = {}

for pair in l:
    key = pair[0].split(',')[0]
    val = int(pair[1])
    try:
        result[key].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        result[key] = [val]

for key, values in sorted(result.items()):
    print(key, sum(values) / len(values))
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you so much and your answer worked!  I spent the whole day trying to figure this out and you did it in less than 15 mins!  Thanks for showing me using a dictionary to aggregate and the enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

You should directly loop over your dictionary instead of converting it to a list first, that's an unnecessary step.

```
# shortened example data:
MyList1 = [('128-F,2825','3'), ('128-F,2854','4'), ('128-F,2913','5'), ('128-F,3210','5')]

result = {}

for key, value in MyDict.items():
    description = key.split(',')[0]
    rating = int(value)
    result.setdefault(description, []).append(rating)

for description, ratings in sorted(result.items()):
    print(description, sum(ratings) / len(ratings))
```

<sub>To avoid lengthy discussions with [Matthias Schreiber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6311436/matthias-schreiber), please note that his answer above was posted a few minutes before mine and that there are some similarities in the structure of his and my code. I have no real motivation to argue around about that, so if you want attribution for whatever, take this.</sub>

Comment: So you basically just copied my example and made a few changes to it. You could have at least mentioned that.

Comment: @Byte Commander, thanks for the answer and showing me I do not need to convert to a list first.  Will keep this in mind and use this next time.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber Although the overall structure is similar (which is no surprise as it answers the same simple question), this is definitely not a copy of your answer. There are quite a few major changes.

Comment: @Byte Commander it seems just too similar to mine and it seems rather unlikely that you didn't see mine before you made yours. But either way, yours is an improvement over mine.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber I *did* see your answer, and yes, the layout of this answer might be *inspired* by yours, but it's far too different to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Byte Commander I'm sorry, that is not what I tried to say. Yours is an improvement over mine, definitely! I just wanted to get some credit for it, that's all.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber Happy now? :P

Comment: @Byte Commander Very :) I did not mean to make this discussion longer than the minuscule importance of the initial message, but thanks.